# Creating a function for a traditional output for integrates

Tags: functions, function-construction

I'm creating a function (`HInt`) for a traditional output for integrates.
For example:

```
HInt[f, x]
```

[image]

If I specify just the domain, like this:

```
HInt[f, {v, V}]
```

I have:

[image]

How to modify my function in order to obtain, the following result, if I specify the domain. In other words, how to set de ScriptCapital letters in my code.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
HInt/:MakeBoxes[HInt[f_,x_],StandardForm]:=RowBox[{"\[Integral]",ToBoxes[f],"\[DoubleStruckD]",ToBoxes[x]}]
HInt/:MakeBoxes[HInt[f_,{x_,x1_}],StandardForm]:=RowBox[{SubscriptBox["\[Integral]",ToBoxes[x1]],ToBoxes[f],"\[DoubleStruckD]",ToBoxes[x]}]
```

Examples to ilustrate:

```
HInt[f, {a, A}]
HInt[f, {s, S}]
HInt[f, {v, V}]
HInt[f, {g, G}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried really hard to explain `ToBoxes` problem in an answer to your recent question.

Comment: I will check...

Comment: Does this question boils down to how to convert `V` to `"\[ScriptCapitalV]"`?

Comment: How to implement `\[ScriptCapital #]` (where `#` can be any letter) in my code. This way every time that I put  `HInt[f, {#, #}]` he gives de integrate output with the ScriptCapital.

Comment: I don't get why do you say `{#,#}` if `{v, V}` has two different characters. What about characters that don't have script capital version? Please provide couple of examples of `HInt[f, ...]` and show what should be the final `RowBox[...]`.

Comment: I added some examples

Comment: This is essentially the same example. What about `{a, B}`, `{a, b,c}`, `{a, 1,2}`?

Comment: Yes, so I didn't understand what you don't get it about the question. Just letters. Two letters. {a,a}, {a,A},{a,g},{A,g}.. any two letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is not very precise I will focus on the core of the problem, namely how to convert `n` to `"\[DoubleStruckN]"`

```
ToDSChar // ClearAll
ToDSChar // Attributes = {HoldAll, Listable};

ToDSChar[n_Symbol] := ToDSChar[#] &@ToString[Unevaluated[n], InputForm]
ToDSChar[str_String] := Which[
  StringLength[str] != 1, str,
  97 <= ToCharacterCode[str][[1]] <= 122, "\\[DoubleStruck" <> ToUpperCase@str <> "]",
  65 <= ToCharacterCode[str][[1]] <= 90,   "\\[DoubleStruckCapital" <> str <> "]",
  True, str
]

ToDSChar[x : Except[_List]] := MakeBoxes[x]

RawBoxes /@ ToDSChar@{a, B, cd, 1, s, expr}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this accomplishes what you want:

First we define the function sc (for Script):

```
sc[symb_] := 
Which[LowerCaseQ[ToString[symb]], 
Symbol[StringJoin["\\[Script", ToUpperCase@ToString[symb], "]"]], 
UpperCaseQ[ToString[symb]], 
Symbol[StringJoin["\\[ScriptCapital", ToUpperCase@ToString[symb], 
"]"]], True, symb]

sc /@ {A, b, 1}
```

[image]

Then we define the function int:

```
int[integrand_, intVar_, lower_] := Integrate[integrand, {intVar, lower, ""}] // HoldForm
```

Then:

```
int[f, sc[a], sc[A]]
```

[image]

Comment: It will fail if `A` or `b` have values.

Comment: @Kuba I didn't think it mattered, because it seems like he's only asking a typesetting question, and he's not trying to typeset values with DoubleStruck or Script.  But I modified it to simply return a value, if given, rather than failing.